# ColdFusion 2016 code separation

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I am getting back into ColdFusion after a few years off (from version 8).
I am changing my approach to web dev in that instead of posting pages to server I am submitting Ajax calls to CFCs to talk to my database.
So far so good but I wondered..

Instead of having lots of inline server ColdFusion code (handy as it is) that set HTML elements like form fields and labels etc.
Can I set these AFTER page load with JS?
I know I probably can but is this sensible and a good approach?
Keeps my client side code clean?

Also strictly a 2nd question but would a dedicated ColdFusion Windows server handle 300 users, max 100 at same time?

Comment: One approach you can use to populate your web page after it loads is with a combination of CF's `<cfsavecontent>` tag and JS's innerHtml function.  I do this in combination with JS's setTimeOut function to refresh `<div>` content.  Whether or not anything is a good approach depends on what you are looking to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach has been to use ColdFusion to simply generate JSON, which I feed into my front-end templates. To generate my JSON, I can still make use of all the CF functions to tweak things when I need.

As for your second question, it will depend on the work your server is doing, but I think in general you shouldn't have any issue. I do some image processing on my servers which adds a lot of load, but I can still handle 300 simultaneous connections without issue. Your milage may vary.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use ColdFusion to merely provide data, you're leaving it up to the front end to create your HTML (fields, labels, etc). 
Since you said that you don't want to inline CF code, this is pretty much your best option (there are other ways to accomplish this, but since you're asking this question, this method will probably be the quickest to get started).

In practice, you'll be creating data, let's say JSON or XML data, that the front end will need to parse and create HTML from.

There are a number of tools out there designed to to what you're describing. I'm not going to weigh in on what the right tools are, but if you research you'll find plenty of pro/cons/implementation details, etc. The word *tools* is important here. Some are frameworks, others aren't. You're looking for JavaScript frameworks, libraries, or plugins that can create or otherwise be populated by the data your CFCs will provide.

You can build your own "UI Framework" by using something like jQuery / jQuery UI (even raw JS) or you can use other tools. AngularJS, React, extJS, etc.

[Here's a link](https://github.com/showcases/front-end-javascript-frameworks) which lists and describes some popular JS front end frameworks.

Secondly, there's not enough information your second question to really answer. A single server with the correct configuration *could*  support 100 concurrent users. But the performance is going to depend on your hardware and software. If you have adequate CPU power, memory, disk I/O, etc, and your software doesn't require extensive resources from the hardware ( think high CPU usage, high memory usage, etc), then you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

While this question is very broad, have my take on it.

As soon as I know I have lots of content, I don't want to generate it at once, but also don't want to show it at once.

I found that jQuery UI's AJAX on tabs was just the ticket to solve both problems

See: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

Below is a ColdFusion-ized version of jQuery UI's approach

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Preloaded</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content1.cfm">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content2.cfm">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content3-slow.cfm">Tab 3 (slow)</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content4-broken.cfm">Tab 4 (broken)</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Later**

I don't really use jQuery UI any more. I now do the same approach with Bootstrap tabs. It requires a little more wiring up, but is still useful.